# how to extract text from ppt, pptx file except footer, slide number using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, extract

I know how to extract text from ppt file using apache poi like this

```
        InputStream fis=new FileInputStream("abcd.ppt");
        HSLFSlideShow show=new HSLFSlideShow(fis);
        SlideShow ss=new SlideShow(show);
        Slide[] slides=ss.getSlides();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x=0; x < slides.length; x++)
        {
            TextRun[] runs = slides[x].getTextRuns();
            for(int j=0; j<runs.length; j++) {
                TextRun run = runs[j];
                if(run != null) {
                    String text = run.getText();
                    builder.append(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it extracts all footer, slide number that I don't want

So how to extract text except footer and slide number

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just skip the text runs you're not interested in?

Comment: @Gagravarr isn't the question about how to programmatically figure out which ones they want to skip? I have the same question.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend that you look at the JPresentation. One of their examples shows how to extract all images and text from all slides: http://www.independentsoft.de/jpresentation/tutorial/exportallslides.html

The API seams to be very easy.

Comment: I don't see how this omits the header and footer text but shapes and text runs is all in POI as well, so presumably there is a way to do this without resorting to questionable commercial software?